# How to do query based on "date" column in sqlite3 using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with sqlite3 but having trouble querying data based on "date" type columns.

Here is my model definition:

```
var sensorData = sequelize.define('Data', 
{
    time: Sequelize.DATE,
    value: Sequelize.FLOAT,
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    source: Sequelize.STRING
},
{
    timestamps : false
});
```

Now I want to get all the records with 'time' later than a given time in this function:

```
function selectData(start_date, num_of_records, callback)
{
    sensorData.findAll({
        limit: num_of_records, 
        where: [time, '???'], <====== How to specify the condition here?
        order: 'time'}).success(callback);
}
```

I can't find any thing on Sequelize's website about 'date' type based query statement.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `where: {time: {gt: new Date(...)}}`?

Answer (score 4):

Just like Soumya says, you can use `$gt`, `$lt`, `$gte` or `$lte` with a date:

```
model.findAll({
  where: {
    start_datetime: {
      $gte: new Date()
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sequelize.fn` like this:

```
where:{timestamp:    gte:sequelize.fn('date_format', fromDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')
            ,lte:sequelize.fn('date_format', toDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')
}
```